# Trying to translate a shirt, I've gotten most of it but I can't figure out this one piece?

Tags: translation, words

it looks like に but with こ instead? is it just an example of how much handwriting can change? or character limitations online? i think the shirt says something like "going home to tokyo street," full shirt graphic for context [image] [image]

Comment: It is に.  Different fonts have minor differences like the placement of serifs.

Comment: BTW the wave dash [should have been flipped](https://bunkyo-kumihan.com/kumihan_blog/?p=5279) in the vertical writing.

Answer (score 1):

It's 東{とう} 京{きょう} 通{とお}り　家{いえ}に帰{かえ}る

Literally that means

> Tokyo Drive, Return Home

Of course this is not a complete sentence but two fragments. But the meaning here is not hard to deduce. Go home via Tokyo Drive. (Drive not as in to drive a car but as in a main road)

Comment: `「東京通り」` `Drive not as in to drive a car but as in a main road` 通りの名称なら「とうきょう**ど**おり」って読みますね